Bhutan without SDF?
To go to Bhutan as a tourist, one must¹

Be part of an authorized tour for US$200 or $250 per day.
Pay an additional “Sustainable Development Fee” (SDF) of US$100 per day
Pay the visa fee US$40

I presume one with a hard-to-get work permit is exempt from this, but what, if any, are the fees (other than normal living costs) for a retired expat who just wants to live there?  Numbeo suggests that I could live in Punakha for $975 a month but just the SDF would make it $3969.  Is a visa or residence permit even possible for retirement?
¹lower costs for a limited number of Asian countries

The Government of Bhutan has issued a list of non-tourist visa categories. If you belong to one of these categories, you are exempted to pay the SDF. From my observation, your current situation might not permit you to live in Bhutan as an expat.
FYI : Until 2027, there is a 50% discount in the SDF. So, the amount in your calculation needs to be halved.

The info I have on the 50% discount said it started September 2023 and changed $200 to $100.  The latter is the amount I used.  The only way I could fit one of those categories would be to enroll in a language class.  That would tie me to one place, preventing seeing the country.  Plus, that document defines non-tourists but doesn't say they are exempt from the SDF, while the one I read about the SDSF said "all visitors" without defining "visitors."  Maybe "visitor" and "tourist" are the same but maybe not.

@WGroleau in most countries "visitor" is a broader category than "tourist" because it includes business visitors, visitors for medical treatment, and so on.  In other words, all tourists are visitors, but some visitors are not tourists.  I don't know about Bhutan, however.
